# oneSignal subscriptions not having user tags

Tags: react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I have a react-native app that uses oneSignal for push notifications so when a user registers to my app I will create that user on one signal from my backend using their id as external_id with their specific tags using external_id as identity identifier so the request is successful but when a user subscribes for push notification from React native app the user tags are not added to the user subscriptions, but after the user subscribed and I try to add that user again from the backend  the user tags are added to the subscriptions how to fix this